# Perl can't Locate existing directory in windows 10

Tags: windows, perl

I am trying to list a files within a directory Doc. Inside this directory there are subdirectories .
One of the subdirectory Directory "user" alone can't be accessed by the perl.
Below is the command

```
 my @ListofFiles = File::Find::Rule->file()
                        ->name( '*.xml' , '*.wav' )
                           ->in( $target_dir );
```

All the xml Files in the subdirectory are listed, except under the directory "user" .
This directory is very much visible in the windows explorer and I am able to interact via cursor.
But perl is not able to access it. When i used the perl command to check if the directory "user" exists or not. It displays **No such Directory is found** .

```
Additional info : Directory "doc" has  following 
             1) Directory "Audio " -> Contains .wav files
            2) Directory "Zip"   -> contains .zip files
            3) Movie.xml
            4) Image.xml
            5) Directory "user"  -> contains .xml
The .wav and .xml files are fethched without any issues
```

am not sure what is the issue here.
Please Help .

Comment: @Dheena Dayalan Did you set right path in `$target_dir`? also is `user` directory hidden/have right permission to view by current user?

Comment: @vkk05 Yes, I did. Also that can be confirmed from the reason that other subdirectories files are listed out from rule query. yes , it does have the right condition.

Comment: @Dheena Dayalan Re: _When i used the perl command to check if the directory "user" exists or not. It displays No such Directory is found_ - Can you paste what command it is?

Comment: *"But perl is not able to access it."* That is a very bad way to describe a problem. You need to say 1) how you create the path in the variable `$target_dir`, 2) how you check what is in the resulting array, preferably a `Data::Dumper` print, and 3) display the file structure of the perl program file in relation to the target_dir. All we can do at this point is guess, you have to supply more information.

Comment: @vkk05 . We have a command to check if the directory exists '-e "C:\\doc\\user" ' . I used this to verify

Comment: I think below might answer your query.

 1) $target_dir = "C:\\doc\\";
             2) my @ListofFiles = File::Find::Rule->file()
                        ->name( '*.xml' , '*.wav' )
                           ->in( $target_dir );
              3) for my $file (@ListofFiles)
                       { print "The available files are $file \n"; }

Comment: @DheenaDayalan No, it did not. Your code works for me, so the issue must be with your file system. You refuse to say what your file system looks like, so we cannot help you any more.

Answer (score -1):

Try executing the below script and let us know if it works for you, also show us the result:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $directory = "C:/doc";

my @subdirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->in( $directory );
print "Subdirectories:\n".Dumper(\@subdirs);

my @ListofFiles = File::Find::Rule->file()
                        ->name( '*.xml' , '*.wav' )
                           ->in( $directory );

print "ListofFiles:\n".Dumper(\@ListofFiles);
```

Comment: Thanks for the your code. But it does not help in my case. however , the same "user" directory in c# it is accessible. when i used xcopy to copy this "user" directory another location , i could see it has "?user" as the name of the directory appended with '?' . This is only visible during xcopy. Does this cause issue , is it unrecognized by perl because of this . But i need a solution in perl.